# How can I convert a JavaScript event to a MochiKitEvent?

Tags: javascript, events, mochikit

How can I convert a normal JavaScript event to a MochiKit wrapped event?

I can't seem to find how to do it anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in the MochiKit source code [Signal.js](http://svn.mochikit.com/mochikit/trunk/MochiKit/Signal.js). You'll find the relevant section is:

```
var E = self.event;
...
new E(src, nativeEvent);
```

To apply this to your own normal js `event`, you could do something like:

```
var mochi_event = new MochiKit.Signal.Event(element, event);
```

Is there an event that Signal.js doesn't cover?